# Update WooCommerce stock status with SQL query if stock value is greater than 0

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

I'm attempting to update a large product catalogue using a SQL query via phpMyAdmin if:

1. the `_stock_status` = `onbackorder`
2. the `_stock` > 0

**Queries attempted:**

```
Update wp_postmeta 
Set meta_value = 'instock' 
Where meta_key = '_stock' 
And meta_value > 0
```

---

```
Update wp_postmeta 
Set meta_value = 'instock' 
Where meta_value = 'onbackorder' 
And meta_key = '_stock_status'
And meta_value > 0
And meta_key = "_stock"
```

---

```
Update wp_postmeta 
Set meta_value = 'instock' 
Where meta_value = 'onbackorder' 
AND '_stock' > 0
```

None of the above have worked.
The last query reduces all stock quantities to 0 but the stock status remains on "backorder"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing those queries, you should join the table **wp_postmeta**. Then you can fix it, for example:

```
update wp_postmeta as tb1 left join wp_postmeta as tb2 on tb1.post_id = tb2.post_id set tb1.meta_value = 'instock' where tb1.meta_key = '_stock_status' and tb1.meta_value = 'onbackorder' and tb2.meta_key = '_stock' and tb2.meta_value > 0
```